# SharePoint Online - Idendifying items with unique permissions with PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

All,

The OOB SharePoint Online OOB permissions tools allow us to identify which items have unique permissions OR which groups and users have unique permissiosn but not both.

Is there a way via PowerShell to identify which items in a document library have unique permissions and to flag up who is actually permissioned on said level.

Thanks
Steven

Comment: perhaps a good starting point? http://ericjalexander.com/blog/2016/11/20/Full-Permission-Report-PowerShell it goes down to the list level, not the file level

Comment: I think you've got insider info!  The link resolve to a page stating the site is being worked on and if I can check back later.

Comment: Has dns resolved this for you yet? If not, I'll copy over the important parts